# How to create a signature pad in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying create a signature pad where I can sign and draw a signature. With a error message that occur if no signature was created when I hit the finish button. I also want a clear signature button that clear the signature pad.

component.html

```
 <div class="container tb-10">
    <form>    
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <h4>Your Signature!</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p style="margin-left:-15px;">I hereby authorize the release to Tax Credit for    Business, Inc. or any state Workforce Agency, any information from any Federal or State Government Agency, including SSA, Dept. of Veterans Affairs or DMV of any State as to my eligibility for Federal or State tax credits.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <p class="pull-left"><strong>Electronic Signature:</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="signaturewrapper">
            
                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <p>Please use your mouse or your finger if you are on a mobile device and sign your name in the space above.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" routerLink ="/home" >Exit</button>
            <button id="submitform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> Finish </button>
        </footer>
    </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signature',
  templateUrl: './signature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signature.component.css']
})
export class SignatureComponent {

}
```